# Extjs align column item to the right

Tags: css, extjs, grid, alignment

I have a problem in aligning an item to the right, or anyway at the end of the column.
As you can see in the picture:

[image]

even if there is space on the right, it aligns the item left covering part of the text (The complete text is "Battery Level"). I would like to align it near the downward arrow.
I tried to use align:'right' without success.

How could I fix it? this is my code:

```
columns: {
        defaults: {
            flex: 1,
        },
        items: [{
             ....
        },{
            text: Strings.positionBatteryLevel,
            hidden:true,
            sortable: false,
            defaults:{
                margin:'-31 0 0 55'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                id: 'batteryFilter',
                align:'right',
                listeners: {
                     change (e,newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {
                        filterGridAttributeType(newValue,'batteryLevel');
                    }
                }
            }],
       },{
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a config for columns to align the content:

```
columns: [{
        text: 'Battery Level',
        sortable: false,
==>     align: 'end'
   },{
        ...
```

Comment: unfortunately, nothing has changed :(

Comment: or anyway it aligns the content of the rows, not the title, on the right.